# Asymptotic distribution of Cauchy location parameter estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, parameter-estimation

I am trying to find the asymptotic distribution of the estimate of the Cauchy location parameter $\theta$:

$X_\text{least integer $\gt{n\over 2}$}$

I know that for a distribution function $F$, the empirical quantile function has asymptotic distribution

$\sqrt{n}\ (X_\text{least integer $\gt{np}$}-x_p) \overset{d}\longrightarrow \text{N}\left(0,\frac{p(1-p)}{f(x_p)^2}\right)$.

Where $x_p$ is the $p$'th quantile.

My question is, if I can just move around and get the result:
$X_\text{least integer $\gt{np}$}\overset{d}\longrightarrow \text{N}(x_p,\frac{p(1-p)}{f(x_p)^2n}+x_p)$.

and then use the $p=1/2$ to get the right result.
$X_\text{least integer $\gt{n\over 2}$}\overset{d}\longrightarrow \text{N}(x_{1/2},\frac{1/2(1-1/2)}{f(x_{1/2})^2n}+x_{1/2})=\text{N}(\theta,\frac{1/4}{f(x_{1/2})^2n}+\theta)$.

I am doubting whether this is correct, but I am struggeling to improve it.

Comment: This makes no sense as written. You can't have $n$ on the right-hand side of a limit for $n\to\infty$. What you wrote is like saying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}=\frac1n$. The fact that the scaled variable converges in distribution means that the distribution of the unscaled variable is asymptotic to what you wrote (just like $\frac1{n+1}$ is asymptotic to $\frac1n$), but you can't write that as a limit.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Very helpful :). What do you think of my solution beside that?